# JQuery: How does Gowalla perform it's "slide" effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How does [Gowalla.com](http://gowalla.com/) perform it's slide effect on the frontpage?

What JQuery effect can mimic that functionality of the sliding down effect?

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery, you can just use [`slideDown`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) to do something similar, however Gowalla seems to use a slightly different method:

The individual panels are inside a parent panel which periodically changes it position. That is, the panels themselves aren't animating, and nothing is even changing size: it's just moving all the panels through a viewport. When it reaches the bottom, the Gowalla page just stops - it actually loads up enough panels for about 4 minutes of sliding - though in your case, you might want to take panels off the bottom and push them back in the top to make it continuous.

Comment: Exactly, which is why I'm asking how this can be accomplished with JQuery. Simply using the SlideDown effect does not accomplish the same functionality GoWalla is doing since it's sliding down all of the content.

Comment: @JGreig - It is animating the `bottom` property, reducing it by 81px every 5 seconds. Look at the jQuery function `animate()` and the built-in function `setInterval`. The rest is CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The aptly named [`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/).

Comment: @Dav, the SlideDown effect does NOT accomplish the same functionality as GoWalla. See @nickf response below as to why

Comment: Actually, it can if you realize that calling slidedown on a *new* element above the existing ones will push the existing ones down. If you want to literally, exactly replicate it, then no, it's not slidedown, but you can accomplish effectively the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think what they are doing is similar to what nickf mentioned.
To create the animation effect, I think all that's done is to animate the position of the div container that wraps around the panels within.

So the parent panel will have a viewport that fits only 6 panels.
Another div container will wrap around all the panels. Use jQuery .animate() to shift the div's top position attribute. Each iteration will shift the div container down by a panel's height (e.g. 100px).

```
var numPanels = 20;
var i = 1;

var livePanel = setInterval(function() {
  if (i < numPanels) {
    $('div.wrap').animate({'top': '+100px'}, 500, 'swing');
    i++;
  } else {
    livePanel.clearInterval();
  }
}, 1000);
```

That's just a rough code of how I think it could work. You also need to take into account the number of panels that will be in the viewport at any one time, and subtract that from the total number of "shifts down" you'll want, in `numPanels`.

Comment: if you want, you can at the end of the whole iteration, set position top: 0px; again to restart. But that would defeat the purpose of a "live" stream if it were to repeat again. Haha. You could load a new set via ajax though...